# Extract Data From Array Google SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm looking to extract a specific line of data from an array in Google SQL.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach this!

My data is structure like this `[id: int64, name: string, path: array{}]` & the table is called `"datatable"`

I want to get the "date_modified" attribute in the array **when "status" changes to "closed"**

[image]

I would like to format my data such that it shows the ID, Name and the date_when it is marked as "closed"

[image]

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you to [handle JSON like this with BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value)

```
# Initialize the data
with raw as (
    select 1 as id, "A" as name, "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"A\",\"date_modified\":\"4/3/2021\",\"status\":\"closed\"},{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"A\",\"date_modified\":\"4/1/2021\",\"status\":\"open\",}]" as path
), 

# Extract the JSON array in a array format
array_extract as(
select id,name, JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(path) as entry from raw
)

# Unnest the JSON array and query in it.
select id, name, JSON_VALUE(e, '$.date_modified') as date_modified 
from array_extract, UNNEST(entry) as e
where JSON_VALUE(e,'$.status') = "closed"
```